# Python - good practice to catch errors

Tags: python

I have these files in my project:

```
- main.py
- module1.py
- module2.py
```

`main` is the main file that will be directly execute in console.

`module1` will be imported into `main` and throws `Module1Exception`.

`module2` will be imported into `module1`, throws `Module2Exception` 
and uses lib that throws `NormalException` and `CriticalException` exceptions.

On all exceptions application should exit.

Which option is a most effective way to catch those errors?
**a)** All exceptions will be catch in `main`, print message and exit
**b)** Lets allow modules to catch exceptions (`module2` catch lib exceptions, `module1` catch only `Module2Exception` and `main` catch `Module1Exception`), print message and exit.
**c)** Like *b*, except that modules will not exit, instead returns False and exit will be called in `main`

**Edit:**

This will be server side application, running as daemon. I expect that in future I will be using multiple servers with global log monitoring, like flume or scribe. Exceptions **must** be caught. These files is only example. In fact, I'm writing a large application which is act as a kind of server. In this moment i write module for load and parse configuration file. In this case script should exit if any exceptions will be raised. And only in this case. After loading the configuration files and pass the tests, the script will be left unattended.

Comment: Why are you catching them?  Unless there's a **reason** to catch them, you should let them propagate.  "print message and exit" is what happens when you write no exception handling code at all.  What are you asking?

Comment: For example, if i get `IOError` while reading file i like to inform user which file caused an exception. Also i like pretty messages, not raw exception data :)

Comment: @Galmi: "i like pretty messages, not raw exception data".  Not really very helpful information.  You get IOError.  Then what?  Stop?  Change something and try again?  The most "effective" way to catch exception depends on (a) what exception and (b) what you're going to do about the exception.  There's no single, simple rule.  It depends on what you're going to do.

Comment: I explain this case in *edit*. This will be server side application, and standard python exception print is.. well, ugly. It is unacceptable to show that message to the customer. So I need to catch **every** exception and change the error message to looks nicer and friendly for the customer.

Comment: @Galmi: Server is not seen by the customer.  Customer uses a client and doesn't see server messages.

Comment: This server is created for customers, not for me ;)

Comment: @Galmi: "i like pretty messages, not raw exception data".  This makes debugging (by your customers) impossible.  Do not hide important information with "pretty" messages.  Your customers will hate you because they can't fix the bugs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`main` should have the responsibility to terminate, not the modules.

What if you wanted to import those modules into another project and you *didn't* want to terminate the application on an exception?